# How do I programmatically update an existing submitted webform submission in Drupal?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-webform

I am attempting to use PHP in Drupal rules to update the values in submitted webform submissions. I can access and view the data correctly. When I assign a new value to a field, it will even show up correctly if I use:

```
print $submission->data[61][0];
```

But, when I navigate to the submission results page, the field is not  updated.

I tried using the `webform_submission_update()` function to push my change, but still no luck.

**Question:** How do I programmatically update an existing submitted webform submission in Drupal?

**Code:**

```
$submission = webform_menu_submission_load($nid, $sid);

// Two ways I've tried to update the data
$submission->data[61][0] = "testwork";
$submission->data[61]['value'][0] = 'Declined';

// If I do print $submission->data[61][0]; it will show the new value.

webform_submission_update($nid, $submission);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was 2-fold:

I didn't use `node_load()` on the NID of the webform.

I didn't use the correct webform function to load the data.

```
// Load the node and submission.
$node = node_load(3333);
$sid = $list_itemb->sid;
$submission = webform_get_submission($node->nid, $sid);
    
// Change submission data.
$submission->data[61][0] = 'Update';
    
// Finally, update the submission.
webform_submission_update($node, $submission);
```

Comment: How does this work in Drupal 9?